# Terraform apply exceeds 1 hour limit of AWS IAM Role chaining

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

My current workflow consists in a Jenkins pipeline managing EKS clusters with Terraform. In certain cases (large clusters) the `terraform apply` step takes well over 1 hour to complete but stops at the 1 hour mark with the following error:

```
Error saving state: failed to upload state: ExpiredToken: The provided token has expired.
```

My situation is: Jenkins assumes role A and then assumes role B to apply Terraform configuration. I read that this is called IAM Role chaining ad has a hard limit of 1 hour by AWS.

Can anyone suggest a workaround to overcome this limitation? Perhaps some way of refreshing the credentials?

I thought Terraform could refresh the credentials by adding the `assume_role {}` block in the provider configuration but it doesn't work. Apparently Terraform can only refresh credentials it requestsed itself.

EDIT: I also tried setting the `assume_role_duration` parameter but it doesn't work beacause:

```
AWS Error: operation error STS: AssumeRole, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: XXXX, api error ValidationError: The requested DurationSeconds exceeds the 1 hour session limit for roles assumed by role chaining.
```

Comment: Is there a single resource which is taking a really long time? I faced the same issue in the past and luckily I was able to workaround it by splitting up the terraform deployment in smaller modules, and running different apply steps for each one

Comment: I've hit a similar error because there was a lot going on, e.g., importing a DB during the build phase to perform some tests.

Comment: @Paolo yes the EKS nodegroup resource alone is taking over 1h to apply. It has over 30 nodes.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is offloading the terraform deployment to an EC2 instance with an instance profile